# Why won't headings of treeview show?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
ship_cargo = ttk.LabelFrame(cargo, height=3, text='Ships', padding=5)
ship_info = ttk.Treeview(ship_cargo, columns=('Manufacturer', 'Class', 'Type', 'Location'),    show='headings')
ship_info.column('Manufacturer', anchor=tk.CENTER, width=30)
ship_info.column('Class', anchor=tk.E, width=30)
ship_info.column('Type', anchor=tk.W, width=30)
ship_info.column('Location', anchor=tk.W, width=60)
ship_info.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=5, rowspan=5, sticky=tk.NSEW)
ship_cargo.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)

cargo.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
cargo.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
ship_cargo.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
ship_cargo.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
```

this code makes the label frame and the tree view and grids it onto a tab of a notebook. However, the headings don't show up when I run the code.

Comment: You need to call `ship_info.heading('...', text='...')` to show the heading text.

Answer (score 0):

@acw1668. Mentioned say call `ship_info.heading('...',`

I re-wrote your code.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

cargo = tk.Tk()

columns = ('Manufacturer', 'Class', 'Type', 'Location')
ship_cargo = ttk.LabelFrame(cargo, height=3, text='Ships', padding=5)
ship_info = ttk.Treeview(ship_cargo, columns=columns, show='headings')

ship_info.heading('Manufacturer', text='Manufacturer')
ship_info.heading('Class', text='Class')
ship_info.heading('Type', text='Type')
ship_info.heading('Location', text='Location')

ship_info.column('Manufacturer', anchor=tk.CENTER, width=30)
ship_info.column('Class', anchor=tk.E, width=30)
ship_info.column('Type', anchor=tk.W, width=30)
ship_info.column('Location', anchor=tk.W, width=60)
ship_info.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=5, rowspan=5, sticky=tk.NSEW)
ship_cargo.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)

cargo.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
cargo.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
ship_cargo.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
ship_cargo.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

cargo.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]